# How do I delete this unneccessary, obscure folder in Vista?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, permissions

I have a hard drive with a long obscure folder name (`26b72166e9fa7bae09463d5c6f90e4`) and subfolders `i386` & `amd64`.

After googling, it seems that it may have been related to various updates/drivers. Right now I just want to get rid of it. This drive is just used for data storage. There is no OS on it.

When I try to delete, the error message says that I do not have permission. When I go to the security tab, I don't have permission to view or edit the objects permission settings.

Suggestions?

**Edit:** Add Spybot Secure Shredder to the growing list of non-working solutions.

Comment: I would recommend changing the 'winodws' tag to the 'windows' tag.

Comment: @Rich, oops ... thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boot on a [LiveCD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Livecd) that support NTFS. I guess most of the Linux live distros can do it (Ubuntu for instance).

From Linux, you should be able to browse your Windows disk and delete the rogue directory.

Comment: I thought about doing this, but I was hoping for a quick answer to do it natively in windows. This may be the only solution, but it requires downloading the ISO if you don't have one handy then burning a CD, then shutting down and booting into another OS, then shutting down and booting back. Plus, if you're using your machine as a server OR in the middle of a some long process, you have to wait or interrupt your work. Sigh ...

Comment: It is always a good idea to have a liveCD hanging around. I use a USB stick I don't need anymore, it's come in handy in many a strange situation. (Need to order pizza, but the phone is dead and the PC won't boot? SOLUTION. (seriously, the phone didn't work. Line was fine, the phone was in two pieces :())

Comment: Ok, this worked. Fortunately, I run Ubuntu virtual machines, so I was able to save myself the trouble of downloading an ISO. I just burned an image from that. Had to change the boot order in my BIOS though ... sigh. I blame Microsoft for turning a simple task into an ordeal.

Comment: You could also have booted the Vista CD in the Vista Recovery Environment and started a Command Prompt. See this link: http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/tutorial147.html

Comment: @Snark, perhaps if the PC manufacturer had given me a Vista DVD.

Answer (score 2):

I would first try booting into safe mode as the Administrator. You  might be able to delete it then.

Also, have you tried deleting it through the Windows command line? I find that sometimes works around finicky Windows issues like this.

Comment: Booting into safe mode doesn't work. Neither does deleting thru the command line. Thx, though.

Answer (score 0):

Such files are typically left around by Windows Update.
If following Matthew's advice doesn't solve the problem, get [Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/). But first verify which is the process that's hogging this directory, just in case.

Comment: Unfortunately, Unlocker is not XP/Vista 64bit compatible. http://ccollomb.free.fr/unlocker/#faq

Comment: Also, I don't think it's related to a process that's preventing the deletion.

Comment: @Keith: it is now, since version 1.9.0 (see the same FAQ)

Answer (score 0):

[This thread](http://www.microsoft.com/communities/newsgroups/en-us/default.aspx?dg=microsoft.public.windowsupdate&tid=55f7835b-1e4e-4531-be2b-c6b75ae0a984) discusses the problem and a solution as below.

```
I am running Windows XP/SP2 and was able to delete the rogue folder this way:
```

1) Disable simple file sharing
 a. In the Control Panel, Select Folder Options, then select the View Tab
 b. Scroll down to the end and uncheck the box next to "Use simple file
sharing (Recommended)"
 c. Click Apply, OK, and exit Control Panel.
2) Change permissions of rogue folder
 a. Navigate to the ed798b66cbeb3a7b9bde9e55a9e2 folder left behind from
the .NET framework update
 b. Right click the folder, select Permissions, then select the Security tab
 c. Under the "Allow" column, click the first box for "Full Control". All
the boxes (or at least most of them) will automatically get checked.
 d. Click Apply then OK.
3) Drag rogue folder to the Recycle Bin. This should delete without a
problem. I told this solution to a friend and he had to go into the rogue
folder and perform step #2 for both the folders present for some reason, but
the end result was the same. The offending folder got deleted.

Comment: These are instructions for XP, but I did the corresponding actions in Vista, and no luck.

Comment: @Keith, have you checked that you actually have sufficient permissions?

Comment: @Nik, do you mean, "Did I try this as an administrator?" Yes.

Comment: This is odd. If Windows has not locked the files (which Unlocker would probably open) and you have sufficient permissions on the station, deleting the files should not be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

If this update hasn't yet been fully applied the files may still be neccessary. If however the update has been applied then you can delete the files.

The Windows Update or BITS services might be locking these files but you can verify what, if anything has a reference to these files using SysInternals FileMon or ProcMon

Comment: It may have be the remnant of an update, but it's definitely not in use any more. It's just a drive that I use for data. I haven't even had it connected for a while.